# Find tmux session that a PID belongs to

Tags: pid, tmux, htop

I am using htop so see what processes are taking up a lot of memory so I can kill them. I have a lot of tmux sessions and lots of similar processes. How can I check which tmux pane a PID is in so I can be sure I am killing stuff I want to kill?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Given that `PID` in the below line is the target pid number:

```
$ tmux list-panes -a -F "#{pane_pid} #{pane_id}" | grep ^PID
```

The above will identify the pane where the `PID` is running. The output will be two strings. The first number should be the same as `PID` and the second one (with a percent sign) is "tmux pane id". Example output:

```
2345 %30
```

Now, you can use "tmux pane id" to kill the pane without "manually" searching for it:

```
$ tmux kill-pane -t %30
```

---

To answer your question completely, in order to find *tmux session* that a PID belongs to, this command can be used:

```
$ tmux list-panes -a -F "#{pane_pid} #{session_name}" | grep ^PID
# example output: 2345 development
```

Here's another possibly useful "line":

```
$ tmux list-panes -a -F "#{pane_pid} #{session_name}:#{window_index}:#{pane_index}" | grep ^PID
# example output: 2345 development:2:0
```

---

The descriptions for all of the interpolation strings (example `#{pane_pid}`) can be looked up in tmux man page in the `FORMATS` section.

Comment: I'm confused.  Accepted answer + upvotes suggests this works.  Yet, at least on tmux 2.8, `#{pane_pid}` is the "PID of first process in pane", which is going to be the shell for everything (i.e. `bash`) unless there's a way to spawn a program directly in a pane without a shell.

Comment: This isn't useful at all as it only gives you the PIDs for "bash", not the actual commands that are running.

Comment: The pids of the commands that are running are children of that bash process, so with `pstree` and `pane_pid` you have what you need

Answer (score 2):

The answers above give you the pids of the shells running in the panes, you'll be out of luck if you want to find something running in the shells.

try:

https://gist.github.com/nkh/0dfa8bf165a53832a4b5b17ee0d7ab12

This scrip gives you all the pids as well as the files the processes have opened. I never know in which session, window, pane, attached or not, I have a file  open, this helps.

I haven't tried it on another machine, tell me if you encounter any problem.

lsof needs to be installed.

if you just want  pids, pstree is useful, you can modity the script to use it (it's already there commented)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following script displays the tree of processes in each window (or pane). It takes list of PIDs as one parameter (one PID per line). Specified processes are underlined. It automatically pipes to `less` unless is a part of some other pipe. Example:

```
$ ./tmux-processes.sh "$(pgrep ruby)"
-- session-name-1 window-index-1 window-name-1
         7184  7170 bash            bash --rcfile /dev/fd/63 -i
         7204  7184   vim             vim ...
-- session-name-2 window-index-2 window-name-2
         7186  7170 bash            bash --rcfile /dev/fd/63 -i
        10771  7186   bash            bash ./manage.sh runserver
        10775 10771     django-admi     /srv/www/s1/env/bin/python /srv/www/s1/env/bin/...
         5761 10775       python          /srv/www/s1/env/bin/python /srv/www/s1/env/bin/...
...
```

`tmux-processes.sh`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu

pids=$1

my_pid=$$
subtree_pids() {
    local pid=$1 level=${2:-0}
    if [ "$pid" = "$my_pid" ]; then
        return
    fi
    echo "$pid"
    ps --ppid "$pid" -o pid= | while read -r pid; do
        subtree_pids "$pid" $((level + 1))
    done
}

# server_pid=$(tmux display-message -p '#{pid}')
underline=$(tput smul)
# reset=$(tput sgr0)   # produces extra symbols in less (^O), TERM=screen-256color (under tmux)
reset=$(echo -e '\033[m')
re=$(echo "$pids" | paste -sd'|')
tmux list-panes -aF '#{session_name} #{window_index} #{window_name} #{pane_pid}' \
| while read -r session_name window_index window_name pane_pid; do
    echo "-- $session_name $window_index $window_name"
    ps -p "$(subtree_pids "$pane_pid" | paste -sd,)" -Ho pid=,ppid=,comm=,args= \
        | sed -E 's/^/        /' \
        | awk \
        -v re="$re" -v underline="$underline" -v reset="$reset" '
            $1 ~ re {print underline $0 reset}
            $1 !~ re {print $0}
        '
done | {
    [ -t 1 ] && less -S || cat
}
```

Details regarding listing `tmux` processes you can find [here](https://serverfault.com/a/914134/162443).

To underline lines I use ANSI escape sequences. To show the idea separately, here's a script that displays list of processes and underlines some of them (having PIDs passed as an argument):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu
pids=$1

bold=$(tput bold)
# reset=$(tput sgr0)   # produces extra symbols in less (^O), TERM=xterm-256color              
reset=$(echo -e '\033[m')
underline=$(tput smul)
re=$(echo "$pids" | paste -sd'|')
ps -eHo pid,ppid,comm,args | awk \
-v re="$re" -v bold="$bold" -v reset="$reset" -v underline="$underline" '
    $1 ~ re {print underline $0 reset}
    $1 !~ re {print $0}
'
```

Usage:

```
$ ./ps.sh "$(pgrep ruby)"
```

Details regarding `less` and `$(tput sgr0)` can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446532/why-do-i-not-need-to-reset-text-attributes-with-less/446541#446541).