# How to find tmux window/pane from a tty?

Tags: tmux

Let's say I have multiple tmux sessions and windows/panes. After awhile, I may have started multiple `vim` in various windows/panes. `ps` would show the `tty`s of all the vim processes. How would I go about finding the tmux window/pane for a given tty?

Comment: I came across a similar question and thought this guide was helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29439835/find-tmux-session-that-a-pid-belongs-to

Answer (score 9):

You to directly jump to some known tty, you can use a combination of `tmux list-panes` with `-F format` and `tmux switch-client`. In the format you can use `#{pane_tty}` abd `#{pane_id}` to shape the output, and then just grep (for example pts/2).

```
tmux switch-client -t $(tmux list-panes -aF "#{pane_tty}:#{pane_id}" | grep pts/2 | grep -oE "[^:]*$")
```

If you're like me and love easy fuzzy selections, pipe a fzf:

```
tmux switch-client -t $(tmux list-panes -aF "#{pane_tty}:#{pane_id}" | sort | fzf | grep -oE "[^:]*$")
```

It can be even more user friendly when you use the pane_title. As you specifically asked for vim, here is how you can dynamically set the title of a pane to the file you are editing in vim (put it into your vimrc).

```
autocmd BufReadPost,FileReadPost,BufNewFile,BufEnter,FocusGained * call system("tmux select-pane -T 'vim | " . expand("%:t") . "'")
```

and then trigger a fuzzy search for it

```
tmux switch-client -t $(tmux list-panes -aF "#{pane_tty}: #{pane_title} :#{pane_id}" | grep vim | sort | fzf | grep -oE "[^:]*$")
```

This will give you much more freedom about what list you have to process than choose-tree as you have the option to filter and (fuzzy)search in the list.

Answer (score 8):

While you could try and do something with `tmux list-panes` using `#{pane_pid}` and grepping over the results, it is likely that your problem could be easier solved with

```
tmux choose-tree
```

It gives a list of the sessions/windows/panes that tmux is running, what is running in those panes, and a snapshot of the pane itself when highlighted.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Those two commands are super useful (thanks for sharing them) although they don't quite solve the problem I described.

Answer (score 0):

```
find /tmp/tmux-$UID -type s -print0 |
  xargs -0i tmux -S '{}' list-panes -a -F '#{session_name} #{window_index} #{pane_tty} #{window_name}' 2>/dev/null |
  grep -w "$(ps -p "$1" -o tty= || echo pts/NO_SUCH_TTY)"
```

I wish `list-panes` took a filter, then it would be even easier.

I call this script `p2mux`.

My answer is a bit complicated (`find | xargs tmux`) because I nest tmux sessions, with `default` being the top-level and all nested sessions being attached each in a window of the same name in the `default` session.  This way I can very quickly find all my workspaces.  I also have a script I call `ntmux` that I give a directory to and it will create a new session named after the basename of that directory, and a new window in the `default` session named the same, and then it will run `tmux -S ... attach-session` in that window -- this makes it trivial to launch new nested sessions.